# How does one create a trigger which when a data set is entered for a new week, a calculation is performed on the previous week's data set in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, automation, triggers, database-trigger

Lets say I have 2 tables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `datasetCalculation`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dataset`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dataset`(
    `datasetID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `datasetWeekOf` DATE, #date indicates the beginning of a week
    `dataInsertedByID` INT NOT NULL,
    `datasetItem1` INT,
    `datasetItem2` INT,
    `datasetItem3` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`datasetID`, `datasetWeekOf`)
    )Engine = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datasetCalculation`(
    `datasetID` INT NOT NULL,
    `datasetWeekOf` DATE,
    `datasetItemSum` INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`datasetID`, `datasetWeekOf`),
    CONSTRAINT `datasetID_FK`
        FOREIGN KEY (`datasetID`)
        REFERENCES `dataset` (`datasetID`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `datasetWeekOf_FK`
        FOREIGN KEY (`datasetID`)
        REFERENCES `dataset` (`datasetID`)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) Engine = InnoDB;
```

What I'd like to do is when `dataset` is updated with the next week's information (it is updated once a week), automatically insert the relevant information into `datasetCalculation`. The equivalent would be to calculate in some language (let's say php) the sum of `datasetItem(1-3)`, then inserting that into  `datasetCalculation`.`datasetItemSum` with the other relevant information. Instead I'd like this to be done automatically by the database.

Comment: Does this thing bump it? Could really use some help here.

Comment: Please explain the nature of calculations, specifically can they be made on a per source row basis or you need to operate with a set of source rows? Also provide sample data before and after calculations in tabular form.